# How to read props when a button is press in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a buttons  and i want to get the name prop of the button when a button is pressed. I am going to doing this as follows and i am getting a number instead of the name prop how can i achieve this

Button

```
      <StatusOption
            name="On going"
            onPress={e => this.onChanged(e)}
          >



      onChanged = (e) => {
         console.log(e.target);
  };
```

How i am able to do so in react native

Answer (score 3):

Alongwith `e` you can pass the second parameter as a prop name.

```
<StatusOption
            name="On going"
            onPress={e => this.onChanged(e,"On going")} > 
                                            ^^^^^^^^
```

And in `onChanged` access it

```
onChanged = (e,propName) => {
             console.log(e.target,propName);
      };
```